# issues with BackGround worker across classes

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

this is my first question in this forum, hope it will not be duplicated somewhere because i have searched for the respons for almost 4 weeks without making any progress.

here is my situation, 
im developing an application that need to do a lot of background operation, for that reason i creat 2 BKW, the first one used to load data from a DB and put it inside an observable collection , 'no need to report progress or support cancelation for this one' :

```
    private Boolean loadTestSteps()
    {
        // Create a background worker thread that  don't report progress and does not
        // support cancelation
        BackgroundWorker wk_LoadTestSteps = new BackgroundWorker();

        wk_LoadTestSteps.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(wk_LoadTestSteps_DoWork);

        wk_LoadTestSteps.RunWorkerAsync();

        return true;
    }
```

observable collection class :

public class clsTestStep : DependencyObject 
    {
        public static DependencyProperty TestStepProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "TestStep", typeof(String), typeof(clsTestStep));

```
    public string TestStep
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TestStepProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TestStepProperty, value); }
    } and so on for the rest of items....
```

now the main backGround that should do the longer operation and in the same time report the progress to the main UI ,declared like so

```
    private void InitializeBackGroundWork()
    {
        _wk_StartTest = new BackgroundWorker();
        // Create a background worker thread that ReportsProgress &
        // SupportsCancellation
        // Hook up the appropriate events.
        _wk_StartTest.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(_wk_StartTest_DoWork);
        _wk_StartTest.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler
                (_wk_StartTest_ProgressChanged);
        _wk_StartTest.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler
                (_wk_StartTest_RunWorkerCompleted);
        _wk_StartTest.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        _wk_StartTest.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        _wk_StartTest.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

in the do work events, exactly in the foreach loop i encontered an error saying : you cannot access this object because another thread own it :

```
    void _wk_StartTest_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        //Loop through each test step and perform Test 
        foreach (clsTestStep item in _testStep)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(200); 
            temp[0] = item.TestStep;
            temp[1] = item.Delay.ToString();
            temp[2] = item.NumberRepetition.ToString();
            temp[3] = item.Mode.ToString();

            //Report % of Progress, Test step Name,and the paragraph from Class PerformTest
            _wk_StartTest.ReportProgress(counter,
                temp[0]);
            counter += 1;

            _performTest.Fdispatcher(temp, out _paragraph);

            //_si.PgBarMax = Convert.ToDouble(_testStep.Count);

        }

        //Report completion on operation completed
        _wk_StartTest.ReportProgress(counter);

    }
```

what im missing here please, because my head is gonna explod from searching !!!

Comment: have tried to use Dispatcher to access info in clsTestStep items but with no luck :     
               Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                  DispatcherPriority.Background,
                  new Action(() =>
                temp[0] = item.TestStep //cannt access to item object :(    
                
            ));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the ones that may enconter this kind of problem ^^
finnaly i have found a way to acess class even if its not owned by the current thread here a nice article explaining step by step how to do this [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20101105144104/http://www.deanchalk.me.uk/post/Thread-Safe-Dispatcher-Safe-Observable-Collection-for-WPF.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your ObservableCollection is created and so owned by an other thread so your _*wk_StartTest_DoWork* method can't access it.

Where your *_testStep* variable comes from ?

By the way, in a multithread environment when many thread access the same data you should prefer the use of ***ConcurrentBag*** class instead of an ObservableCollection. ConcurrentBag is thread safe.

Comment: hello FloChanz thanks for your reply ^^ , my _testStep object is filled by data coming from mysqlDataBase and _testStep is observablecollection too.

Comment: No sorry I don't see why it's in error. Is it crashing when accessing the TestStep property of your item or before ?
Can you just try to add a ToList() on the _testStep variable : 
foreach (clsTestStep item in _testStep.ToList())

Comment: thanks FloChanz your  comment gives me some ideas to think of ^^